# How to do error handling in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm using Jmeter to do a load testing for a website.

JMeter does not show errors other than 404 errors.

How can I get the error messages in JMeter for the errors that occur for other cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, JMeter only flags typical HTTP error response codes, like 4XX and 5XX errors.

You should use Response Assertions on your HTTP samplers if you wish to have finer control over what is flagged as an error.

Comment: If the answer resolved your question, you should consider marking it up. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use 404 code as a success also. When you put your assertion with 404, there is a checkbox in the corner that says 'Ignore Status'. This will treat also 404 as a success.

Answer (score 1):

One annoyance with this though seems to be that JMeter always treats a 404 as an error, when can be a valid response for some applications.  So even if you make an assertion that a 404 response is OK, it will still show as an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java code Executer Like beanShell  to execute the piece of code that take error code of previous call and end save in a jmeter variable

```
String errorcount;
errorcount = Integer.toString(ctx.getPreviousResult().getErrorCount());
vars.put("errorcount", errorcount);
```

and evaluate the "errorcount" in if controller or can capture a particular text to by Boundry Extractor

```
{__javaScript(("${errorcount}"!= "0") || ("${value}" == "NotFound" ))}
```

and in the if controller this code can be used to continue next iteration in BeanSampler

```
ctx.setRestartNextLoop(true);
```